# Is there a way to have more relevent variable names in a loop?

Tags: python, loops, variables

I have a list that follows the format :

`message = [sender, receiver, message_name]`

I have to loop through all my messages stored in my **message_stack** list and assess for each message whether its name is valid (*i.e* if its name is in the valid_names list)

For the moment I have :

```py
for message in message_stack:
    if message[2] not in valid_names:
        print("Error : wrong name.")
```

The iterator **message** has a relevant name but is there a way to make `message[2]` a bit clearer regarding the face that it is a message name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use iterable unpacking:

```
for sender, receiver, message_name in message_stack:
    if message_name not in valid_names:
        print("Error : wrong name.")
    # do some more stuff with sender, receiver....
```

Terminology note, `message` is not the "iterator". Iterator has a specific meaning in Python (that which is returned from `iter` when you do `iter(iterable)`, i.e. `iterator = iter(iterable)`). You might call it the "loop variable"

Comment: Thx for the precision and the answer !

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
for sender, receiver, message_name in message_stack:
    if message_name not in valid_names:
        print("Error : wrong name.")
```

You can even omit sender and receiver if you won't be using them:

```
for _, __, message_name in message_stack:
    if message_name not in valid_names:
        print("Error : wrong name.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use star unpack to get last element:

```
for *_, message_name in message_stack:
    if message_name not in valid_names:
        print(some_thing)
```

Or consider using `namedtuple` when creating lists:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Message = namedtuple('Message', ['sender', 'receiver', 'name'])
message_stack = # a list of Message object
for message in message_stack:
    if message.name not in valid_names:
        print(some_thing)
```